# Implementation of Permutation Algorithm A from Topor, 1982

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, combinatorics, f#

This is **Algorithm A** from [Functional Programs for Generating Permutations](https://github.com/shaunluttin/algorithms/blob/master/articles/functional-programs-for-generating-permutations/article.pdf) (Topor, 1982). The author states that the algorithm was described in TAoCP Vol 1.

[image]

We have implemented Algorithm A in F# as follows.

```
let rec put (a: 't) (p: List<'t>) (q: List<'t>) : List<'t> =
    if p = q then a :: q
    else p.Head :: (put a p.Tail q)

// a: an element
// p: a list of elements
// q: a sublist of p
// ps: a list of permutations
let rec insert (a: 't) (p: List<'t>) (q: List<'t>) (ps: List<List<'t>>) : List<List<'t>> =
    if q.Length = 0 then (put a p q) :: ps
    else (put a p q) :: (insert a p q.Tail ps) 

let rec mapinsert (a: 't) (ps: List<List<'t>>) : List<List<'t>> =
    if ps.Length = 0 then List.empty<List<'t>>
    else insert a ps.Head ps.Head (mapinsert a ps.Tail)

// x: a list of elements
// returns a list of permutations
let rec permute1 (x: List<'t>) : List<List<'t>> = 
    if x.Length = 0 then [x]
    else mapinsert x.Head (permute1 x.Tail)
```

Here is a usage example

```
permute1 [1;2;3] |> List.iter (printf "%A ")
// [1; 2; 3] [2; 1; 3] [2; 3; 1] [1; 3; 2] [3; 1; 2] [3; 2; 1]
```

We would like a review to make our F# more canonical. That is, we would like to adjust our code to be in keeping with common F# styles and techniques.

Alternatively, we would like a reviewer to show alternative techniques (if not better ones) for implementing **Algorithm A** in F#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echoing Henrik's answer, I'd agree that the implementation looks fairly idiomatic already.

The only material change I'd make is changing all uses of `List.length` to explicit pattern matching with an empty list case.  This is because `List.length` is an O(n) call due to the linked list implementation of F# Lists, when all you really care about is if the list is empty. As an example:

```
module AlgorithmA =
  let rec put a p q =
    if p = q then a :: q
    else p.Head :: (put a p.Tail q)

  // a: an element
  // p: a list of elements
  // q: a sublist of p
  // ps: a list of permutations
  let rec insert a p q ps =
    match q with
    | [] -> put a p [] :: ps
    | _::qs as q' -> put a p q' :: insert a p qs ps

  let rec mapInsert a ps =
    match ps with
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs -> insert a x x (mapInsert a xs)

  // x: a list of elements
  // returns a list of permutations
  let rec permute1 x = 
    match x with
    | [] -> [[]] // return an list containing the empty list 
    | x::xs -> mapInsert x (permute1 xs)
```

Comment: You demonstrated three alternative techniques. Pattern matching, removing the type annotations, and using `[]` instead of `List.empty<'t>`. I had figured that the compiler would complain about the use of `[]` for an empty list. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: take a look at the implementation of List.empty [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L118), you can see that the compiler itself uses `[]` in this way. `[]` and `List.empty` are just two names for the same value.  You also don't necessarily need to provide a type argument `'t` for `List.empty` most of the time. The compiler can infer what the 't should be based on usage.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing much to say about the implementation of the algorithm itself. It seems to be a fairly one-to-one implementation of the pseudo code and it looks rather functional to me.

You could though avoid all the argument declaration if you change a few things in the functions as shown below.

Beside that I prefer to encapsulate recursive functions in a wrapper function but that - I think - is a matter of taste:

```
    let permuteA data = 
        let rec put a p q =
            if p = q then 
                a :: q
            else 
                p.Head :: (put a p.Tail q)

        // a: an element
        // p: a list of elements
        // q: a sublist of p
        // ps: a list of permutations
        let rec insert a p q ps = 
            if q |> List.length = 0 then 
                (put a p q) :: ps
            else 
                (put a p q) :: (insert a p q.Tail ps) 

        let rec mapinsert a ps = 
            if ps |> List.length = 0 then 
                [] 
            else 
                insert a ps.Head ps.Head (mapinsert a ps.Tail)

        // x: a list of elements
        // returns a list of permutations
        let rec permute1 x = 
            if x |> List.length = 0 then 
                [x]
            else 
                mapinsert x.Head (permute1 x.Tail)

        permute1 data
```

---

**EDIT**

I admit that Husk has a point about `List.length`especially in `mapinsert`where the length reach as much as `(n - 1)!` but tests on my computer shows only a pair of seconds in expense for n = 8. The algorithm exhausts the stack for n = 10 anyway...

As an alternative you could use `List.isEmpty` which seems to have the same performance as Husks version.

Comment: Thank you for demonstrating the removal of type annotations and demonstrating the `q |> List.length` approach. I was surprised to see that we could use `[]` to represent an empty list. I thought that the compiler would throw a type error due to the vagueness of the empty list's type.

Comment: It was also good to learn about encapsulating the recursive function.